# Grim pdf to png in ruby using grim

Tags: ruby, pdf, png

I run the below code for pdf to png conversion using grim

```
 pdf = Grim.reap(File.dirname(__FILE__)<<"/pdf.pdf")
 count = pdf.count
 pdf[3].save('like.png')
 text = pdf[3].text

 pdf.each do |page|
   puts page.text
 end
```

It shows following error:

> No such file or directory - gs -dNODISPLAY -q -sFile=./pdf.pdf 
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grim-1.3.0/lib/pdf_info.ps (Errno::ENOENT)
>   from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grim-1.3.0/lib/grim/image_magic
>   k_processor.rb:21:in `count'
>   from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/grim-1.3.0/lib/grim/pdf.rb:35:i
>   n`count'
>   from pdfpng.rb:18:in `'"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Ghostscript dependency is missing as that provides the `gs` binary, or you do have that installed but it's not present in your `PATH`.